# NodeJS - Promise resolve returns empty object

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, server, promise

I've been rewriting my very simple server lately. I have been trying to introduce promises but for some reason, even though my mongoDB database has data in it (in this case a list of categories) when I call the below method that I have written it returns an empty json object {}. I have tried multiple methods. It was a very simple method before this which worked fine, I am trying to update it to allow for more complex requests.

Does anyone have any idea why I may be getting an empty object returned? It returns 200 OK in postman so I do not believe there is any errors.

This is my Controller class:

```
'use strict';
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Category = mongoose.model('Categories');

module.exports = function() {
    var mod = {
       listAllCategories() {

         return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

           Category.find({}, function(err, category) {
              if (err) {
                return reject(err)
              } else {
                return resolve(category)
              }
            });
          }).then(([category]) => {

            if(category)
            {
              return category
            }
            else
            {
              return { success: false }
            }
          });
       }
     }
     return mod;
};
```

Here is how I am calling this method in my Routes class:

```
  app.get('/api/gameCategories', (req, res) => {
    res.json(gameCategoryList.listAllCategories())
  })
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `res.json` on a promise object, not the value it would resolve to.

So do like this:

```
gameCategoryList.listAllCategories().then(category => res.json(category));
```

There is something else that looks suspicious in your code: `new Promise` resolves to `category`, but in the `then` callback you treat it like an array (which may very well be correct), but you only extract the first array element from it (by destructuring it). If that was not intended, then remove the square brackets from the `[category]` parameter.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much. That worked a treat, I will accept it as the answer once it allows me to. Any idea as to why it is only returning the first category rather than all of them? I am assuming it could be to do with the way I am returning it in the resolve?

Comment: Nevermind, I was correct...it should have been just category rather than [category]. Thanks again!